# how do i free a memory block when i have to return it back?

Tags: c, struct, linked-list

I have this function for my linked list, and i have to return it as a journal (struct). when i run valgrind, i found out that i have a memory leak here, which is the malloc. I am wondering to how can i free `entry`? or is there a way to return the data inside the entry without creating a new object(? idk what its called)

```
Journal *removeStart(LinkedList *list) {
    Node *front;
    Journal *entry = malloc(sizeof(Journal));
    front = list->head;
    entry = front->data;
    if (list->head==NULL) {
        entry = NULL;
    }

    list->head = list->head->next;
    front->next = NULL;

    if (front == list->head) {
        list->head = NULL;
    }

    free(front);
    return entry;

}

Journal *removeLast(LinkedList *list) {
    Node *end;
    Journal *entry = malloc(sizeof(Journal));


    if (list->head == NULL) {
        entry = NULL;
    }

    end = list->head;
    while (end->next != NULL) {
        end = end->next;
    }
    if (list->head->next==NULL) {
        entry = list->head->data;
        list->head = NULL;
    }
    else {
        entry = list->head->data;
        end->prev->next = NULL;
    }


    free(end);
    return entry;

}
```

my struct for journal is

```
#define SIZE 102
typedef struct {
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
    char entry[SIZE];
} Journal;
```

Comment: You don't need to malloc at all. `list->head->data` will be the pointer to the data you want to return.

Comment: so i just create a new node to store that data? or all i have to do is just return it as is? 
```return list->head->data```

Comment: basicly, but you still have to free the node that holded the pointer and make sure that the list doesn't have a pointer to the freed node.

Comment: @Ackdari but for my remove last function, i require to return the value in the ```if (list->head->next==NULL)``` part, and i would like to not use multiple returns, is it possible?

Comment: I think you just need to check if `end` is `NULL` and if it is not set `entry = end->data` and `end->prev->next = NULL`